# Create a 2 RecyclerView vertical scrolling into horizontal scrolling?

Tags: android-recyclerview

android : I can have the code 2 recyclerview vertical scroll into horizontal scroll ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR0ok.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Nested-RecyclerView.

Check this:
https://github.com/jeffreyliu8/Nested-RecyclerView